# Bizspark Member - Microsoft SQL Server License

Tags: sql, licensing, bizspark

I have recently joined Bizspark programme and however, I am confused by the Microsoft SQL Server license for Bizspark members.

**Question (1):**

I can find **SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition with Service Pack 1 (x64) - DVD (English), SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition with Service Pack 1 (x64) - DVD (English) etc** from MSDN but it said that "No product key is required", what does it really mean? Is it a trial version or licensed version?

**Question (2):**

I am developing web based solution (I will charge user subscription fee) using Microsoft ASP.NET with MVC framework. If I used Microsoft SQL Server as database and installed in VPS or dedicated server, do I still have to pay for the license (Core / CAL) since I have joined Bizspark programme. What about after three years, after my Bizspark membership expired, if I am happy with older version of Microsoft SQL server, can I continue using Microsoft SQL server with the pre-given Bizspark license (serial key) without paying anything.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **licensing** and not programming...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key is embedded in to the installer for you.

The licensing question is complex and you likely need to work with Microsoft on this.  I'm currently working with them on very similar questions, but related to utilizing Azure for hosting my application.  The Bizspark SQL Licensing may not actually cover the way Azure utilizes SQL.